# JavaScript - How to filter array based on a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an object like so:

```
nameArray = dataArray.map(function (item) {
  return {
    value: item.Title,
    title: item.Title,
    id: item.Id,
    location: item.Location,
    telephone: item.Telephone,
    address: item.Address,
    postcode: item.Postcode,
    category: item.Category
  };
});
```

Then I am doing some filtration to filter out closed locations and return a final array for processing:

```
var CClose = "C Closed";
var Cclosed = "closed";
var CClosed = "C closed";

//for each item if its closed remove it
//push it to standard list 
standardAZList = $.map(nameArray, function (val, key) {
  if (val.category != CClosed || val.category != Cclosed ||
    val.category != CClose)
    return val;
});

for (var i = 0; i < standardAZList.length; i++) {
  //filteredAZList.push(standardAZList[i]);
  alert("After removing name count is inside remove:" +
    standardAZList.length);
}
```

However I am getting the wrong number of items back of 160, but the filter should only show back 110 (some are `null` in Category which don't matter).

Comment: where is your filter function?

Comment: `if(val.category != CClosed || val.category != Cclosed || val.category != CClose)` this seems to be always true imo

Comment: Thanks guys, just trying a .filter action now.... ;-)

Comment: Sorted it by doing the filter:  `let filteredAZLista = nameArray.filter(c => c.category !== "C closed"  && c.category !== "closed" && c.category !== "C Closed");
           // filteredAZList = nameArray.filter(location => location.category !== Cclosed || CClose || CClosed)

            alert("" + filteredAZLista.length);
            
            for(var i=0;i<filteredAZLista.length;i++){
                  standardAZList.push(filteredAZLista[i]);
                  alert("After removing name count is inside remove:" + standardAZList.length);
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this after helpful comments above:

```
//Filter first
let filteredAZLista = nameArray.filter(
c => c.category !== "C closed" && 
c.category !== "closed" && 
c.category !== "C Closed"); 

alert("" + filteredAZLista.length); 

//Loop through
//And Push out
for(var i=0;i<filteredAZLista.length;i++){ 
     standardAZList.push(filteredAZLista[i]); 
    alert("After removing name count is inside remove:" + standardAZList.length); 
}
```